How to Ensure Database Clean-Up After Test Completion in Spring Boot?
I am utilizing the following technology stack
spring-boot : 3.0.0
JUnit5
H2(In-Memory)

The issue is that data remains in the database even after one test case has ended.
I attempted to use JUnit 5's Extension to clean up the database contents after the tests have finished.
However, upon executing the tests, I observed that the data saved in the registMemberTestIfEveryThingsIsOk method persists, causing the second assertThrows in the registMemberTestIfOauthPlatformHasInvalidValue method to not throw anything.
testCode
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(DataClearExtension.class)
class AuthServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;
    @BeforeAll
    public static void initDataBase(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource("/sql/member_test.sql"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
       ...


    @Nested
    class registMemberTest {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource(value = {"123, google, yongjun, 213, kevinH, 20000928, male, student, red, img",
                "2, kakao, hannah, 314, alex, 19980512, female, engineer, blue, img",
                "3, apple, david, 415, emma, 20010320, male, designer, green, img",
                "4, kakao, sarah, 516, michael, 19991225, female, developer, yellow, img",
                "5, google, emily, 617, chris, 19921005, female, manager, orange, img"})
        void registMemberTestIfDuplicatedIdExist(@AggregateWith(MemberAggregator.class) MemberRegistRequestDto memberRegistRequestDto) {
            assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> authService.registMember(memberRegistRequestDto));
            
            Member member = authService.findMemberByOAuthId(memberRegistRequestDto.oauthId());
            assertAll(
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.name(), member.getName()),
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.nickname(), member.getNickname()),
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.birth(), member.getBirth())
            );
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource(value = {"101, naver, yongjun, 213, kevin, 20000928, male, student, red, img",
                "102, git, hannah, 314, alex, 19980512, female, engineer, blue, img",
                "103, microsoft, david, 415, emma, 20010320, male, designer, green, img",
                "104, samsung, sarah, 516, michael, 19991225, female, developer, yellow, img",
                "105, wooabros, emily, 617, chris, 19921005, female, manager, orange, img"})
        void registMemberTestIfoauthPlatformHasInvalidValue(@AggregateWith(MemberAggregator.class) MemberRegistRequestDto memberRegistRequestDto) {
            assertAll(
                    () -> assertThrows(UnknownOAuthPlatformException.class, () -> authService.registMember(memberRegistRequestDto)),
                    
                    //the error ocurred here!
                    () -> assertThrows(MemberSigninException.class, () -> authService.findMemberByOAuthId(memberRegistRequestDto.oauthId()))
            );
        }

    }

      ...


    static class MemberAggregator implements ArgumentsAggregator {
        @Override
        public Object aggregateArguments(ArgumentsAccessor argumentsAccessor, ParameterContext parameterContext) throws ArgumentsAggregationException {
            return new MemberRegistRequestDto(argumentsAccessor.getString(0), argumentsAccessor.getString(1), argumentsAccessor.getString(2), argumentsAccessor.getString(3),
                    argumentsAccessor.getString(4), argumentsAccessor.getInteger(5), argumentsAccessor.getString(6), argumentsAccessor.getString(7), argumentsAccessor.getString(8),
                    argumentsAccessor.getString(9));
        }
    }
}

member_test.sql
CREATE TABLE member
(
    id                 BIGINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    oauth_id           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    oauth_platform     ENUM ('APPLE', 'GOOGLE', 'KAKAO'),
    name               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    profile_img        VARCHAR(255),
    nickname           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    birth              INT,
    gender             VARCHAR(255),
    profession         VARCHAR(255),
    signature_color    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    create_date        DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_modified_date DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY oauth_id (oauth_id)
);

INSERT INTO member (oauth_id, oauth_platform, name, profile_img, nickname, birth, gender, profession, signature_color)
VALUES ('123', 'GOOGLE', 'hong', '123123', 'kevin', '0928', 'male', 'student', 'red'),
       ('2', 'GOOGLE', 'muny', '123123', 'anna', '0929', 'female', 'developer', 'blue'),
       ('3', 'GOOGLE', 'kim', '123123', 'jenny', '0930', 'female', 'professor', 'black'),
       ('4', 'GOOGLE', 'karina', '123123', 'katarina', '1000', 'female', 'developer', 'pink'),
       ('5', 'GOOGLE', 'down', '123123', 'mark', '1001', 'female', 'teacher', 'skyblue');


public class DataClearExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        DataCleaner dataCleaner = getDataCleaner(extensionContext);
        dataCleaner.clear();
    }

    private DataCleaner getDataCleaner(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        return SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext)
                .getBean(DataCleaner.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class DataCleaner {

    private static final String FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK_FORMAT = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS %d";
    private static final String TRUNCATE_FORMAT = "TRUNCATE TABLE %s";

    private final List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void findDatabaseTableNames() {
        List<Object[]> tableInfos = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC'").getResultList();
        for (Object[] tableInfo : tableInfos) {
            String tableName = (String) tableInfo[0];
            tableNames.add(tableName);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void clear() {
        entityManager.clear();
        truncate();
    }

    private void truncate() {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(String.format(FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK_FORMAT, 0)).executeUpdate();
        for (String tableName : tableNames) {
            entityManager.createNativeQuery(String.format(TRUNCATE_FORMAT, tableName)).executeUpdate();
        }
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(String.format(FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK_FORMAT, 1)).executeUpdate();
    }

yaml
spring:
  datasource :
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

error message
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected com.fixadate.global.auth.exception.MemberSigninException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3083)
at com.fixadate.global.auth.service.AuthServiceTest$registMemberTest.lambda$registMemberTestIfoauthPlatformHasInvalidValue$7(AuthServiceTest.java:109)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.lambda$assertAll$0(AssertAll.java:68)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:2912)
at com.fixadate.global.auth.service.AuthServiceTest$registMemberTest.registMemberTestIfoauthPlatformHasInvalidValue(AuthServiceTest.java:107)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestTemplateMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:94)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:204)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:142)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$2(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:110)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:110)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:44)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

After debugging, it was found that the findDatabaseTableNames method in the DataCleaner class failed to retrieve the table names, as the size of tableInfo was 0.

Thus, I thought the issue might lie in the failure to retrieve tables from H2. However, please let me know if there might be any other mistakes I made elsewhere.
Documents I've Read

JUnit, JPA and Spring: How to ensure that unit tests leave database clean on completion
H2 in memory database doesn't show tables created in spring boot


I hope you have a great day. Thanks for reading through the long text.


try adding the annotation @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) and converting @BerforeAll method to non-static and adding @AfterAll method, as shown below:
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(DataClearExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class AuthServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;
    @BeforeAll
    public void initDataBase(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource("/sql/member_test.sql"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void cleanUpDataBase(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        // clean up code goes here
    }    

@Nested
    class registMemberTest {
        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource(value = {"123, google, yongjun, 213, kevinH, 20000928, male, student, red, img",
                "2, kakao, hannah, 314, alex, 19980512, female, engineer, blue, img",
                "3, apple, david, 415, emma, 20010320, male, designer, green, img",
                "4, kakao, sarah, 516, michael, 19991225, female, developer, yellow, img",
                "5, google, emily, 617, chris, 19921005, female, manager, orange, img"})
        void registMemberTestIfDuplicatedIdExist(@AggregateWith(MemberAggregator.class) MemberRegistRequestDto memberRegistRequestDto) {
            assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> authService.registMember(memberRegistRequestDto));
            
            Member member = authService.findMemberByOAuthId(memberRegistRequestDto.oauthId());
            assertAll(
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.name(), member.getName()),
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.nickname(), member.getNickname()),
                    () -> assertNotEquals(memberRegistRequestDto.birth(), member.getBirth())
            );
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource(value = {"101, naver, yongjun, 213, kevin, 20000928, male, student, red, img",
                "102, git, hannah, 314, alex, 19980512, female, engineer, blue, img",
                "103, microsoft, david, 415, emma, 20010320, male, designer, green, img",
                "104, samsung, sarah, 516, michael, 19991225, female, developer, yellow, img",
                "105, wooabros, emily, 617, chris, 19921005, female, manager, orange, img"})
        void registMemberTestIfoauthPlatformHasInvalidValue(@AggregateWith(MemberAggregator.class) MemberRegistRequestDto memberRegistRequestDto) {
            assertAll(
                    () -> assertThrows(UnknownOAuthPlatformException.class, () -> authService.registMember(memberRegistRequestDto)),
                    
                    //the error ocurred here!
                    () -> assertThrows(MemberSigninException.class, () -> authService.findMemberByOAuthId(memberRegistRequestDto.oauthId()))
            );
        }

    }

      ...


    static class MemberAggregator implements ArgumentsAggregator {
        @Override
        public Object aggregateArguments(ArgumentsAccessor argumentsAccessor, ParameterContext parameterContext) throws ArgumentsAggregationException {
            return new MemberRegistRequestDto(argumentsAccessor.getString(0), argumentsAccessor.getString(1), argumentsAccessor.getString(2), argumentsAccessor.getString(3),
                    argumentsAccessor.getString(4), argumentsAccessor.getInteger(5), argumentsAccessor.getString(6), argumentsAccessor.getString(7), argumentsAccessor.getString(8),
                    argumentsAccessor.getString(9));
        }
    }
}


How can I delete data from an H2 (in-memory) database? I'm not sure how to do it. Could you please provide me with an SQL statement?
It seems very good idea to me :)

do you mean to drop table "member" in @AfterAll method? Also, you are using h2 embedded database right? The database will drop when all the test cases are executed.

I want to delete data after one case is closed. And I want to delete columns from a table, not drop the table.
sorry for writing the sentence confusingly.
